# Octave, how to save a plot graph?

Tags: image, plot, save, octave

I need to save a plot. This is my code that I don't know why it does not work.

```
hold on;
plot(x1, y2)
plot(x1, y2)
print -djpg image.jpg
```

The plot in output on screen is correct, but the output in the file is different: it saves only an empty plot image without my points.

This is my output in the file:
[image]

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest GNU Octave release which is [3.8](http://mxeoctave.osuv.de/). I remember seeing this issue before with other users.

Comment: What operating system? What if you change the extension to let's say *.png or *.pdf? Have you tried the alternative `print (FILENAME, OPTIONS)` syntax?

Comment: SO : "Ubuntu 13.10". I tried to save in variuos extensions file (png, pdf etc.) but the result is always the same.

Comment: What if you try with a different graphics toolkit? Restart the interpreter and type `graphics_toolkit fltk` or `graphics_toolkit gnuplot` right before the plot commands.

Answer (score 12):

I just had the same issue with the latest Octave (3.8.1). This issue comes from GhostScript, not Octave. There's a bug with the management of fonts.

To make sure, check in your console after you try to print if this error is outputted (along with a lot more infos):

```
GPL Ghostscript 8.63: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

If that's the case, then try this:

```
set (0, "defaultaxesfontname", "Helvetica") % this is the line to add BEFORE plotting
hold on;
plot(x1, y2)
plot(x1, y2)
print -djpg image.jpg
```

This will fix the problem by setting a font that GhostScript can handle without any issue. Note that if you already plotted the figure, you will have to close it and replot it after setting defaultaxesfontname.

Source: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=710272

Comment: Using this method I get a black screen printed. However at least I can save it as an image directly. print still doesn't work.

Comment: Check that your version of Ghostscript is compatible with Octave, you may have to update/use an older version in order for the print to work correctly. You can also report your issue on Octave's tracker.