# Octave: Output Statements and Plots to PDF

Tags: octave

I have a dataset with dates, times, pressures and temperatures. I currently have it going through and creating two plots: Pressure vs. Time and Temperatures vs. Time. On top of this, I have a user input field to state their name, which all gets mixed to output a statement containing the user's name and current date.

I want to output the statement mentioned above, as well as the two plots generated into a simple .PDF document, which then will get submitted as the final result for review. I started with outputting images, but I cannot get the commands I have found to work... any attempt I make causes the program to freeze and crash. This was the main question I had followed in order to create my code: [Octave, how to save a plot graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23779819/octave-how-to-save-a-plot-graph)

Outside of that, I am failing to grasp and understand how to output a .PDF document directly based on this documentation: https://docs.octave.org/octave.pdf

Sample of data being processed:

```
230915;13:51:52;1;1;9.000E+2;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;19.6;19.1
230915;13:51:53;2;2;9.000E+2;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;19.6;19.1
230915;13:51:54;3;3;9.000E+2;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;19.6;19.1
230915;13:51:55;4;4;9.000E+2;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;19.6;19.1
230915;13:51:56;5;5;9.000E+2;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;19.6;19.1
230915;13:51:57;6;6;9.000E+2;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;19.6;19.1
230915;13:51:58;7;7;9.000E+2;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;19.6;19.1
230915;13:51:59;8;8;9.000E+2;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;19.6;19.1
230915;13:52:00;9;9;9.000E+2;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;-;19.6;19.1
```

Here is a basic overview of what I have setup:

```
p = [10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1];                #p, tc1, tc2 are values pulled from a array of data
tc1 = [19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19];
tc2 = [19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19];
pts = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];

subplot(2, 1, 1);
p_plot = plot(pts, p)
subplot(2, 1, 2);
t_plot = plotyy(pts, tc1, pts, tc2);
print -dpdf image.jpg
```

The addition of `print -dpdf image.jpg` alone causes the program to freeze and crash outright.
As a test, I created a super simple plot to attempt a test output:

```
x = [1 2 3]
y = [1 2 3]
plot(x,y)
print -dpdf image.jpg
```

Again, a crash... unsure what I am doing wrong with the process.
Thank you for any help!

Comment: I'm able to run the print command without a crash.  I do notice that you're creating a PDF and naming it .jpg. On my system the file is created, but opening it the image viewer gives me an unsupported file error until i rename it to image.pdf.  at that point my pdf viewer loads the file just fine.  

is a file produced before the crash?  what operating system, Octave version, and install method did you use?

Comment: @NickJ Went ahead and changed "image.jpg" to "image.pdf" in the code. Ran the script, same deal--freeze and crash. OS: Windows 11 - 21H2; GNU Octave version: 8.3.0; Install method: .EXE (octave-8.3.0-w64-installer.exe)

Comment: And no file output either.

Comment: Read the documentation and honour the order of arguments. It may be as simple as calling it with the filename first and options second. Alternatively try calling it in functional form instead of command form. Alternatively you can also try the "savefig" function.

Comment: it might be worth posting this issue to the primary octave help forum at https://octave.discourse.group to troubleshoot the crash.  it may be worth doing gdb backtrace as per https://wiki.octave.org/FAQ#Collecting_gdb_backtrace_information and posting the results over there

Comment: Cheers everyone, thank you for the inputs. I'll be reporting the issue to Octave's discussion area & wiki. In the meantime, I have essentially abandoned Octave and used Python to successfully complete my task.