# Print a pdf plot in Octave

Tags: plot, octave, gnu, octave-gui

I'm trying to print a pdf plot in GNU Octave. The graph is shown on the plot schreen. Unfortunately the plot does not show the full graph when opening the plot in the PDF document.

[PDF document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mobW.png)

Strangely enough the issue does not occur when I print the plot in png, `print(h,'Test.png',"-dpng")`. Below i have made an example code to illustrate the problem. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

```
close all
clear all
clc

x = [0:0.001:1]';
y = zeros(size(x,1),10);

y(:,1) = arrayfun(@(x) x^(1/5),x);
y(:,2) = arrayfun(@(x) x^(1/4),x);
y(:,3) = arrayfun(@(x) x^(1/3),x);
y(:,4) = arrayfun(@(x) x^(1/2),x);
y(:,5) = arrayfun(@(x) x,x);
y(:,6) = arrayfun(@(x) x^2,x);
y(:,7) = arrayfun(@(x) x^3,x);
y(:,8) = arrayfun(@(x) x^4,x);
y(:,9) = arrayfun(@(x) x^5,x);
y(:,10) = arrayfun(@(x) x^6,x);

h = figure
hold on

for i = 1:10
  plot(x,y(:,i))
end

grid

set(gcf,'papert', '<custom>')
set(gcf,'paperunits','centimeters');
set(gcf,'papersize',[29.7 21])
set(gcf,'paperposition', [1 1 27.7 19])
set(gcf,'defaultaxesposition', [0.15, 0.15, 0.75, 0.75])
set (0,'defaultaxesfontsize', 11)
print(h,'Test.pdf',"-dpdf")
```

Thanks in advance

P.S Using version 8.4.0 at this moment.

Thomas

I tried printing png and pdf.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I can't reproduce the bug on my machine, so this may possibly be related to shared libraries rather than the octave core per se. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39746234/4183191) for a similar issue I had way back, maybe it'll be of help. If not, I would advise you to search / open a bug on the bug tracker like I did in the linked post. :)

Comment: Hi Tasos, Thanks for your answer. I use Octave on a windows machine so i asume the linux packages will not give a better result. I can be wrong because i dont know what ' libgl2ps1' does. I also found a similar problem where Ghostscript caused the problem, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23779819/octave-how-to-save-a-plot-graph) Link. But i have no idea how i can find the root of this problem.

Comment: I have submitted this issue as a bug => [bug#65051](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?65051)

Comment: `y = arrayfun(@(x) x^(1/5),x)` is more easily expressed as `y = x.^(1/5)`.

Answer (score 0):

I reported this problem as a bug on https://savannah.gnu.org/. It turns out that when using a windows installer you need to select "SoftWare OpenGL Driver" in the setup wizard in stead of using the default settings. After reinstalling Octave with this setting the rendering of the plots worked fine.

Thomas